# Why am i not able to install tflite-model-maker?

Tags: python, pip, tensorflow-lite, anaconda3

I am trying to install tflite-model-maker on my Anaconda environment. By using this Input in my cmd.

```
pip install tflite-model-maker
```

But the installation ends with this error:

```
 Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [68 lines of output]
      C:\Users\jnaga\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uziw6g0d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:293: _DeprecatedConfig: Deprecated config in `setup.cfg`
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.

              By 2023-Oct-30, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
              or your builds will no longer be supported.

              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is due to the newer Cpython and PyYaml version, so try reverting them to an older version.

`pip install "cython<3.0.0"`

`pip install "pyyaml<5.4"`